# How to make several libraries under same parent path in Python

Tags: python, python-packaging

Suppose I have `library1`

```
.
└── mycompany/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── library1/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── file1.py
        └── file2.py
```

And `library2`:

```
.
└── mycompany/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── library2/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── code1.py
        └── code2.py
```

They both have parent directory of `mycompany` and own `__init__.py` file inside.

Will this work? How can I install these libraries? Won't `__init__` files conflict?

Comment: What do you mean with install? Like [publishing packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)?

Comment: Maybe "[*namespace packages*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/)" is the key word you are looking for. If yes, then the right way of doing this ("[***native** namespace packages*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages)) is without any `__init__.py` file at all in the namespace packages. So in your case there should be no `my_company/__init__.py` in `library1` nor `library2`. If you follow this, you are pretty much done. `library1` and `library2` can be installed together without conflict.